# Import parameters from config, but create the config first if it does not exist

Tags: python, import

I have some global constants, that are saved in a .py file and that are needed at many different places in the codebase:

```py
from important_parameters import ROOT_DIR, ANOTHER_DIR
```

This import is needed in many files, and is more convenient than passing it around all the time, I think.
The issue is, that these parameters depend on the user, i.e. these are relative directory paths. That is, the config file must be created first, if another user runs the script. So I was thinking about something like this:

```py
if not os.path.exists('important_parameters.py'):
   args = parser.parse_args()
   create_params_file(args)
```

the arguments could be be specified at the top, for example:

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    '--root_data_dir', type=str,required=True
)
parser.add_argument(
    '--another_data_dir', type=str, required=True
    )
```

afterwards, we can create the config file:

```py
def create_params_file(args):
    with open('important_parameters.py', 'w') as file:
        file.write(f'ROOT_DIR = "{os.path.join(args.root_data_dir)}"\n')
        file.write(f'ANOTHER_DIR = "{os.path.join(args.another_data_dir)}"\n')
```

and use an if condition in the main block:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not os.path.exists('important_parameters.py'):
        args = parser.parse_args()
        create_params_file(args)
```

However, this does not work if the file does not exist, because then I get an import error at the top. Any elegany solutoin for my situation?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing to do is importing the importan_parameter directly in the main function after the if statement

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not os.path.exists('important_parameters.py'):
        args = parser.parse_args()
        create_params_file(args)

    from important_parameters import ROOT_DIR, ANOTHER_DIR
```

Answer (score 0):

Your imports are not actually global constants if they are provided at runtime by the user.

By importing a module, Python will run that modules code and create its namespace, hence the error as the code for the import has not yet been generate since Python is looking to first create the namespace of that import.

In terms of a solution you have several options, but none that are truly recommended:

#### Option 1

Declare a global variable, assign this from the user input and use across the different files:

```
# module.py #

ROOT_DIR = None
# arg parser gets user input...
ROOT_DIR = args.root_data_dir


# other_file.py #

import module

global ROOT_DIR

if ROOT_DIR is not None:
    print("Do something")
```

#### Option 2

Add the variables to a modules namespace:

```
# main.py #

import module

user_input = input("Enter a value: ")

# Adding a variable to module's namespace
module.ROOT_DIR = user_input

# Now, you can use the variable in the module
module.foo_or_bar()

# module.py #

def foo_or_bar():
    if ROOT_DIR == "foo":
        print(ROOT_DIR)
    else:
        print("bar")
```